# How can I create configMap from a file in a different Git repository using Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I know that I can use Kustomize's configMapGenerator to create a configmap from a file that resides in the same Git repository as the "kustomization.yaml" file.

For Example:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  files:
  - config-file.json
```

But is it possible to create a configMap from a file that resides in a different Git repository?

For example:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  files:
  - git::ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:7999/proj/repo-name.git//config-file.json
```

Comment: Kustomize is not able to fetch individual files from a remote repository, but it can treat a remote repository as a `resource` if it contains a `kustomization.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach for the use case you describe is just to define a `base` and create a specific overlay that references the remote base and includes the file you need, merging the configs:

```yaml
# base-project/base/kustomization.yaml

apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  files:
  - config-file.json
```

Then on your other project:

```yaml
# some-other-project/kustomization.yaml

apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - https://bitbucket.company.com/base-project//base?ref=v1.0.0
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  behavior: merge
  files:
  - config-file.json
```

The double slashes are relevant and `ref` can be any branch or tag (e.g. `main`); I used https but you can also setup direct git references or use rewrite rules, see https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/remoteBuild.md.